# Is there any way to determine what process has triggered an Application onCreate?

Tags: android, firebase

Basically, we've got a bunch of sdks and whatnot that start up in the app's oncreate code.

However, even if the app is force closed, android will boot up the oncreate just to show a push notification.

I'm trying to switch code paths based on whether or not the app was actually launched or if the app was just kicked awake by a service or receiver.

While I know I can use the intents for this, because it happens in a background, I can't actually get an intent from an activity to determine this.

Comment: "I'm trying to switch code paths based on whether or not the app was actually launched" -- perhaps that code should not have been in an `Application` `onCreate()` in the first place. "Is there any way to determine what process has triggered an Application onCreate?" -- the process is always an OS process. If you mean that you want to determine what *event* is causing your `Application` to be created, AFAIK we don't have a way of determining that.

Comment: Frustrating! Whenever a push is received, the whole oncreate process runs and does a bunch of stuff that we only want to happen if the user actually _opened_ the app. 

Its a bunch of things that get processed before the main activity starts (first launch feature flags etc), so we retrieve as soon as possibe... But we don't want to retrieve that if the main activity isn't going to open!

Comment: Perhaps [use `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks) and only do that work when the first activity is invoked for your process. Or, explore [Jetpack Startup](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/startup).

Comment: Yeah that's the only way it looks like. As a note, the jetpack startup will be called in these scenarios as well. LifeCycleEventObserver will treat the event as a Create too so you can't distinguish